# Should I synchronize KeyListener Methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, awt

I want to make a game which involves listening to key inputs. I know that a common strategy is to create a boolean array with each key code, so you can check the status of any key at any time. However, I don't know whether or not I should synchronize access to the keys.

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setVisible(true);
        Game g = new Game();
        j.addKeyListener(g.mylistener );
        while(true){
            g.update();

        }
    }

    boolean[] keys = new boolean[KeyEvent.KEY_LAST + 1];

    GameKeyListener mylistener = new GameKeyListener();

    class GameKeyListener implements KeyListener {

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            synchronized (keys) { //Is this necessary?
                keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            synchronized (keys) { //Is this necessary?
                keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
            }
        }

    }


    static final int SPACE = KeyEvent.VK_SPACE;
    public void update() {
        synchronized (keys) { //Is this necessary?
            if (keys[SPACE]) {
                //this code should run repeatedly while space is pressed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that concurrent access to the keys will crash my program. However, blocking the listener thread stops all UI function. Should I synchronize access to the keys?

I have searched and found another question asking the same thing, but there are two contradicting answers that both bring valid points.

Here is the other question:
[Should input listeners be synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14924926/5770298)

Comment: There's no contradiction. You're code is all called on a single thread, the GUI event thread, so there's no need to synchronize. You've got no off thread code, so you can disregard the accepted answer and follow the other answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: thank you! However, the idea was that the update() method would be callled in a loop directly from the main thread, but the KeyListener calls would happen in the GUI event thread.

Comment: Is this a Swing GUI? You should make all GUI calls on the GUI thread.

Comment: I want to make a game, and I intended the update() method to represent logic that would control the game, not the GUI. I added a main method to clarify. The update method runs on the main thread, but the key methods happen on the GUI thread.

Comment: So it is Swing. Use a Model-View-Controller structure, run the model on the Swing event thread, but have long-running code run off this thread using a SwingWorker.

Comment: Regardless, don't use synchronize for code that runs on the event thread. Never. This answers your question.

Comment: ... and use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not a KeyListener.